# Is it ever preferred to decouple the actionscript from the timeline using addFrameScript?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

There's an undocumented addFrameScript method within that's part of the MovieClip class.  Apparently some people use that method to omit writing any code within frames in the timeline and put all their code in a single, separate .as file (ex. Maintimeline.as).

I feel the actual frames and the shapes and objects in them lose their physical significance when you decouple the code from them and put them in another file.

Is this method ever preferred and are there any practical examples where this is commonly done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote an article about a year ago about how to keep all your "timeline goodness," yet still use good OOP practice as described by Creynders and Mr./Ms. Sausages http://www.developria.com/2010/04/combining-the-timeline-with-oo.html . I did a presentation for the Atlanta Flash and Flex User Group, including files, based on that article, that you can check out here http://www.meetup.com/atlflex/files/ .

Answer (score 2):

It's *always* preferrable to decouple graphics from code. The only code permissable in a MovieClip would possibly be a `stop()` command, though it's better to work around that.

Personally, I don't use `addFrameScript()` as I find it easier to just associate the graphics with a particular class (either through exporting it in Flash, or creating a class and adding the MovieClip as a property). It's much cleaner to work with and stands up better should either the graphics or the code change.

Comment: I agree with @divillysausages, though in addition to `stop()`, I also allow `dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE))` on the last frame for animations so you can execute code that needs to happen after an animation is complete. That would be my only other exception though.

Answer (score 2):

I try to avoid writing any code in the timeline ever, because they make things very unmaintanable:

- frames get added/removed w/o regards to the code
- symbols get overwritten
- decentralisation of code (meaning you got code for a MC in a .as file, but also in the .fla, so you always need to go check in the .fla what is going on where

Also it's far easier to work with a designer/animator if you leave out all timeline code. All you need is a few guidelines that need to be strictly followed:

- for the designer: whenever something needs to happen at a certain frame, create a label with a semantic name, the developer can use those labels to get the frame number
- for the developer : NEVER EVER EVER add framescripts based on frame number only (except some kind of initialisation on frame 1, but even then) ALWAYS use labels!

Now there's actually one case in which I DO write code on the timeline itself, and that's strictly to stop a linear animation with one end point and no pauses. That's it.

-- EDIT --

It happens VERY seldomly you really need to a framescript, most of the times you can solve it differently, which is always preferrable.

Answer (score 1):

I often wonder about the same thing myself. Been programming too long not to see the absolute benefit in leaving the code out, but I'd definitely like to - in my mind - still maintain the link between the timeline and certain events. It's a tool, so obviously just abandoning it's a silly idea.

Besides, you can programmatically retrieve both the current frame of a movie-clip and the corresponding label.

http://adobe.ly/osU3A6 - current frame property

http://adobe.ly/o1JVn5 - list of frame labels

Write a listener on ENTER_FRAME that will check movie-clip labels. You could even write a nice little service that would provide a centralized place to register listeners w/ some kind of special "label syntax".

Something like this:

LabelDispatcher.addEventListener( movieClipTarget, frameLabel, callBackFunc );

I haven't actually ran this and I'm sure it'll be full of bugs but the service could look something like this:

addEventListener( target:movieClip, frameLabel:String, callBack:Function ):Boolean {

```
   this.internalListOfListens.push( { target:target, frameLabel:frameLabel, callBack:callBack } );
```

}

When you're ready to start acting on the frame labels, register this Listener on the Stage's EnterFrame:

public function labelListenerPulse( event:Event ):void {

```
for( listenedTo:Object in this.internalListOfListens ) {

       var target:MovieClip = listenedTo.target as MovieClip;

       if ( target.currentFrameLabel == listenedTo.frameLabel ) {

            var callBack:Function = listenedTo.callBack as Function;

            callBack( new Event( blah blah blah... ) );   

       }

 }
```

}